# Tokenize a string

Tags: c++, parsing

I used `strtok` to tokenize a string. But many developers said me to avoid `strtok`, why? How should I optimize this code? Is it really wrong that I used `strtok`? If so then with what should I replace it?

```
DWORD FN_attack_speed_from_file(const char *file)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(file, "r");
    if(NULL == fp)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    int speed = 1000;
    const char *key = "DirectInputTime";
    const char *delim = " \t\r\n";
    const char *field, *value;
    char buf[1024];
    while(fgets(buf, 1024, fp))
    {
        field = strtok(buf, delim);
        value = strtok(NULL, delim);
        if(field && value)
        {
            if(0 == strcasecmp(field, key))
            {
                float f_speed = strtof(value, NULL);
                speed = (int)(f_speed * 1000.0);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return speed;
}
```

I would like to modernize this as C++, and learn modern coding.

Comment: `strtok` is a valid function in C++. It's not wrong to use it in C++, it's not necessarily that much faster or slower. But your C++ code will look better if you avoid `strtok`.  If you want to move to C++ then it's more important to use `std::fstream`, `std::getline` and `std::string` which have significant advantage over their C counterpart, you would end up avoiding `strtok` as well.

Comment: you also can use std::regex for split string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I used strtok to tokenize a string. But many developers said me to avoid strtok, why?

Because `strtok()` modifies the input is the main reason.
But it has other issues that make it not a good option in modern code.

> How should I optimize this code?

Well let us make it correct first before we go for optimizations. But `strtok()` will probably be the fastest. That's because it basically does nothing but tokenization. But this also makes it dangerous to use.

> Is it really wrong that I used strtok?

Yes if you are using C++. The better technique is to code for type safety and re-usability. The difference in speed will be minimal. So small that if this program is running for years that even the cumulative time saves by `strtok()` will not amount to the time taken to fix a single bug by a human.

> If so then with what should I replace it?

You should probably use the C++ stream operators.

#### C++ Version

```
 // Slightly different to the original.
 // If the value part has an illegal character for a float it
 // will probably mess up.
 DWORD FN_attack_speed_from_file(char const* fileName)
 {
     std::ifstream file(fileName);

     std::string   field;
     float         value;
     while(file >> field >> value)
     {
         if (field == "DirectInputTime") {
             return value * 1000.0;
         }
     }
     return 1000;
}
```

Comment: See here please how i use it  http://prntscr.com/cnzg8d

Comment: @Ramy: My code is going to fail on that because it will not correctly handle the line `{`. But I am sure you can take what I have given you and extend it to your needs.

Answer (score 4):

Since you have indicated that you are using C++, you should use idiomatic C++ approaches to parse input.  In particular, you should avoid `strtok()`, which is not recommended even in C, since it is not thread-safe.

It appears that you are looking to read whitespace-delimited [words](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) and [floats](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt).  For that, use the `>>` operator on an [`ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream).